# Jigsaw Blade for Hardibacker

Tags: tile, ceramic-tile, saw, backer-board

I am cutting some 1/2" Hardibacker into some 2" x 32" sections.  I tried using a 6 TPI wood jigsaw blade but the blades are not lasting very long.  Does anyone know if a diamond tipped or carbide tipped would last longer?

Comment: Yes score and break, if you need to cut a lot of angles like i had to, cheap blades is your best bet.  I was able to extend the life of the blades by putting a piece of 3/4 inch plywood on top of the hardier board first and then removing it for another cut.  The jigsaw blade then gets worn down in 2 places vs. one.

Answer (score 1):

Score with a utility knife, clamp between scraps of wood, and snap.

If you don't have enough extra length to snap with, the best tool I've found is a grinder with a diamond blade. (Use outdoors with appropriate PPE.)

If you have to use a jigsaw blade, then yes, the grit ones will certainly outlast a wood blade, but not by much. (And maybe not enough to justify the added cost.)